# Как отправить видео из бота на python?

Tags: python, бот

Собственно суть в заголовке. Как отправить видео из бота при нажатии определенной кнопки. Делал отправку фото из бота, указывал путь до фото и отправлялось через send_photo. Пробовал send_video, но ничего не получилось. Выдает ошибку.

Comment: Какой бот, какая кнопка, какое видео и какая ошибка, мы сами должны догадаться?

Comment: @andreymal видео отзыв. При нажатии на кнопку "отзывы" должно приходить это видео. библиотека pytelegtambotapi.